# View "ChangePassword" in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, passwords

Can you help me to build my "ChangePassword" View in MVC3 ?

*Here what I have tried to do:*

**ProfileTeacherController.cs**

```
public ViewResult ChangePassword(int id)
    {
        var user = User.Identity.Name;
        int inter = int.Parse(user);

        var teachers = from t in db.Teachers
                       where t.AffiliationNumber == inter
                       select t;

        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
        foreach (var teach in teachers)
        {
            teacher = teach;
        }

        return View(teacher);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(Teacher teacher)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // How can I compare the two fields password in my view ?
            db.Entry(teacher).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "ProfileTeacher", new { id = teacher.TennisClubID });
        }
        return View(teacher);
    }
```

**Here the ChangePassword (View)**

```
@model TennisOnline.Models.Teacher
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ChangePassword";
}

<h2>Changement du mot de passe</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Enter the new password")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Pin, new { value = Model.Pin })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Confirm your password")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Password("ConfirmPassword")
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

So, How can I verify in my controller if the two passwords are the same, please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the usage of a view model:

```
public class TeacherViewModel
{
    ...

    [Compare("ConfirmPassword")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

now have your view take the view model and also your Post action.

In addition to that in your GET action you seem to have written some `foreach` loop which I don't see its usage. You could simplify:

```
[Authorize]
public ViewResult ChangePassword(int id)
{
    var user = User.Identity.Name;
    int inter = int.Parse(user);
    var teacher = db.Teachers.SingleOrDefault(t => t.AffiliationNumber == inter);
    return View(teacher);
}
```

Comment: Thank you It works great ! And thanks also for the tips about the "foreach loop"

Answer (score 5):

In addition you can add the message to be shouwn when the two password are not the same in the Compare attribute.

```
[Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirm password do not match.")]
```